# C# - Converting object to int without casting

Tags: c#

I have a method that returns a type of object based on the given column (a database class). However, when I assign the object the compiler throws an error saying it cannot implicitly convert type of object to int. How can I convert it without casting?

It looks better as:

```
this.Id = datum["Id"];
```

But now I have to include a cast, which makes the code a bit less clean and harder to code:

```
this.Id = (int)datum["Id"];
```

Here's my code:

```
public object this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            object result;

            if (this.Dictionary.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                if (this.Dictionary[name] is DBNull)
                {
                    result = null;
                }
                else if (this.Dictionary[name] is byte && Meta.IsBool(this.Table, name))
                {
                    result = (byte)this.Dictionary[name] > 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = this.Dictionary[name];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = default(object);
            }

            return result;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value is DateTime)
            {
                if (Meta.IsDate(this.Table, name))
                {
                    value = ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                }
                else if (Meta.IsDateTime(this.Table, name))
                {
                    value = ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                }
            }

            if (this.Dictionary.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                this.Dictionary[name] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Dictionary.Add(name, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You *could* change your indexer signature to:

```
public dynamic this[string name]
```

That would then make the conversion dynamic at execution time.

Personally, I prefer the cast approach though. It makes it clear that this is something that can fail - that you're telling the compiler that you have information which isn't available to it.

As an aside, your code can be written rather more simply, taking advantage of `Dictionary<,>.TryGetValue` and the behaviour of the dictionary indexer for setting:

```
public object this[string name]
{
    get
    {
        object result;
        if (Dictionary.TryGetValue(name, out result))
        {
            if (result is DBNull)
            {
                result = null;
            }
            else if (result is byte && Meta.IsBool(this.Table, name))
            {
                result = (byte) result > 0;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    set
    {
        // TODO: Byte/bool conversions?

        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            // Note use of invariant culture here. You almost certainly
            // want this, given the format you're using. Preferably,
            // avoid the string conversions entirely, but...
            DateTime dateTime = (DateTime) value;
            if (Meta.IsDate(this.Table, name))
            {
                value = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            else if (Meta.IsDateTime(this.Table, name))
            {
                value = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }

        Dictionary[name] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used the dynamic approach before. However, after a few tests I figured out it's really slow and slows down my program by a lot of time. So, I changed this approach.

Comment: +1 for answering the question AND politely suggesting with a voice of expertise that fewer characters is not always better.

Comment: @JonSkeet If I use dynamic /only/ when returning the objects by a given column, would it slow down my application? My approach before that was making the class that holds the dictionary a DynamicObject, however, I changed that because it was too slow. If I do use dynamic but only when returning the object, would it also be slow as before?

Comment: @GilbertWilliams: There's an easy way to tell, isn't there? I'd be surprised if this were *actually* a bottleneck - but as I say, I'd personally stick with the cast.

Comment: @JonSkeet Why would you though? And also, there's a mistake in your code. The CultureInfo should come after the string in the ToString method.

Comment: @GilbertWilliams: Fixed, thanks. I've explained why I would in the answer - it's more explicit, telling anyone reading the code "I'm doing a conversion here - I hope it's right."

Comment: However, I believe casting is more beneficial in terms of execution time. if you use Convert.ToInt32(datum["Id"]); I think it is done at execution time and if you cast (int)datum["Id"]; it is done at compile time (e.g. the compiler optimize this). Even if Convert would be done at compile time under the hood it would still have the overhead of calling additional instructions.

Comment: @GillsoftAB: The conversion itself has to be done at execution-time either way. I'd be surprised to see a situation where performance would be the governing factor here. Desired behaviour in various situations and readability are far more important, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Use class `Convert`:

```
Convert.ToInt32(datum["Id"]);
```

Comment: I know how to convert, but it still looks less clean. Is there a way to make the method somehow return the type that is needed? The dictionary is a collection of <string, object>. The string is the column of the table and the object is the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't need to state in your code that you are casting from `object` to `int`, then the programming language would not be helping you avoid mistakes.

C# does have a feature where you can switch off static type checking for specific variables: make your indexer return `dynamic`:

```
public dynamic this[string name]
```

Then you'll be able to say:

```
int n = datum["Id"];
```

But the downside is that you won't find out if this is correct until runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an extension method.

Create a class like this.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static int AsInt(this object obj)
    {
        return (int)obj; // add additional code checks here
    }
}
```

Then in your actual code all you have to do is call the extension method like this.

```
this.Id = datum["Id"].AsInt();
```

I know this may look the same as the cast but it happens underneath the method call `AsInt` and your code is cleaner and easier to read since `AsInt` is fluent and definitive.

Comment: @GilbertWilliams Thanks, if you're satisfied with the answer, please do upvote and mark as answer so this question can be closed.

Comment: Following normal .NET naming conventions, it would be better as `AsInt32` or `ToInt32`.